# Python config parsing with unspecified type

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, configuration

How to parse this type of configuration file:

```
log-messages   1
log-buffer-size 1
log-max-lines 200
```

in python 3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could read it to a dictionary:

```
config = {}
for line in open('file_name.conf'):
    key, value = line.split()
    config[key] = int(value)
```